# What does this menu item mean in Xcode menu?

Tags: xcode

[image: Xcode Menu]

It's available only under Xcode 3.x. The hands-like tab between Windows and Help.
What is this tab used for?

Comment: Looks like it's probably something to do with code signing? Or maybe licensing? It's not hands, it's a scroll of paper. Also... it is for a version of Xcode that is 6 years old. You should not be using it.

Comment: AppleScript is my guess.

Answer (score 0):

[Xcode 3.2.6](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wVudm.png)

After trying by myself.  It is actually User Scripts as the image shows.
And it's gone since Xcode 4 onwards.
Reference: 
https://devforums.apple.com/message/380673#380673